# count of distinct of column for each value in another column

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a table like below in `MySQL`. I want to select `serial_num`, `devicetype`, `device_model` and `distinct of timestamp for each serial_num`

```
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------------+
| serial_num  |   devicetype    | device_model  |        timestamp       |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+------------------------+
| 58172A0396  |                 |               | 2003-01-02 17:37:15.0  |
| 58172A0396  |                 |               | 2003-01-02 17:37:15.0  |
| 46C5Y00693  | Mac Pro         | Mac PC        | 2018-01-03 17:17:23.0  |
| 1737K7008F  | Windows PC      | Windows PC    | 2018-01-05 11:12:31.0  |
| 1737K7008F  | Network Device  | Unknown       | 2018-01-05 11:12:31.0  |
| 1737K7008F  | Network Device  | Unknown       | 2018-01-05 11:12:31.0  |
| 1737K7008F  | Network Device  |               | 2018-01-06 03:12:52.0  |
| 1737K7008F  | Windows PC      | Windows PC    | 2018-01-06 03:12:52.0  |
| 1737K7008F  | Network Device  | Unknown       | 2018-01-06 03:12:52.0  |
| 1665NF01F3  | Network Device  | Unknown       | 2018-01-07 03:42:34.0  |
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

I have tried like below

```
select
    serial_num,
    devicetype,
    device_model,
    count(distinct timestamp)
from table
group by serialnum, devicetype, device_model
```

The result I want is

```
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
| serial_num  |   devicetype    | device_model  |count|
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
| 58172A0396  |                 |               |  1  |
| 58172A0396  |                 |               |  1  |
| 46C5Y00693  | Mac Pro         | Mac PC        |  1  |
| 1737K7008F  | Windows PC      | Windows PC    |  2  |
| 1737K7008F  | Network Device  | Unknown       |  2  |
| 1737K7008F  | Network Device  | Unknown       |  2  |
| 1737K7008F  | Network Device  |               |  2  |
| 1737K7008F  | Windows PC      | Windows PC    |  2  |
| 1737K7008F  | Network Device  | Unknown       |  2  |
| 1665NF01F3  | Network Device  | Unknown       |  1  |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a little confused as to what you want. Can you please add another table to show your **desired** result?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have edited the question Please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the table to itself on just the serial number to get the count:

```
select
    t1.serial_num,
    t1.devicetype,
    t1.device_model,
    count(distinct t2.timestamp)
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.serial_num = t2.serial_num
group by 1, 2, 3
```

This allows every row of the table to be in the resulting rows, while finding all timestamps, which requires hitting other rows.

Comment: Very good. I only recommend not to group by column number, but by column name. The column name would be the (ungiven but probably existing) primary key from  the table, something like GROUP BY t1.id.

Comment: @roemer using column numbers in the group by clause is a style choice. I prefer the brevity of numbers, because the expression (which may be long/complicated) must be repeated if non-aggregated, which goes against DRY principle and creates a maintenance overhead and possible bug source if using MySQL (as here) because (depending on settings) omitting columns from the group by is allowed, which could silently break the result if only the column expression is changed. Using numbers avoids all these problems, is shorter to code and has no downside.

Comment: I completely understand, however, it is vulnerable for bugs if you later decide to change anything in the query, esp. the column order. Anyway: best is to group by primary key, if present, I think we can agree on that. ;)

Comment: @Roemer well, sometimes primary key isn’t what you want to group by (as here), but is often the case. As for the column order changing, I *always* put the non-aggregate fields *first* in the select list, so changing column order is not a problem. BTW, I’ve used numbers for 20 years and never had a single bug or problem of any kind. As an aside, it is obvious that the entire `group by` clause is redundant and it should be formally made optional in the SQL language.